# Snowflake serverless task creation returns error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

when trying to create a task using

`create task if not exists <task_name> SCHEDULE = '3 minute' USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL' AS <sql>`

I am getting this error

**SQL compilation error: Missing option(s): [WAREHOUSE]**

Comment: I’m guessing this preview feature (USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE) is not yet available in your account/region

Answer (score 4):

I think the documentation is not yet clear (it has been raised) but...

If you are going to grant the ability to run tasks against the serverless warehouse to a custom role, please ensure you grant both "Task" and "Managed Task" to that role.  (Failure to grant these rights has tripped up a few of our customers and staff)

```
use role accountadmin;
grant execute managed task on account to role my_task_role;
grant execute task on account to role my_task_role;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should grant `'EXECUTE MANAGED TASK'` on account level to the role.

`GRANT EXECUTE MANAGED TASK ON ACCOUNT TO ROLE (ROLE_NAME);`